# iOS 7: SKStoreProductViewController not displaying on 64 bit

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7

The SKStoreProductViewController (which loads the iTunes store in app) does not appear to load on iOS 7 compiled for 64 bit.

I have tested Xcode 5 running on 32 bit and the SKStoreProductViewController loads fine, however, when run on 64 bit, it does not display. The rest of my app seems fine on 64 bit.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if any error is being returned in the completion block and if so what it is?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: I have tested Xcode 5 running on 64 bit and the SKStoreProductViewController loads fine.Can you provide us some other information?